Effective version for Silverman’s specialization theorem
In his paper, Silverman proves Theorem C (page 208, the indexes of the pages don't match the file), which says that the set $$\{t\in C^0(\bar{K})\mid \sigma_t \text{ is not injective}\}$$ is a set of bounded height, but I'm wondering what can be said on this bound (effective in terms of... and so).
The only part of the proof of Theorem C that can be proved effectively is Theorem B (page 206), which lead to an effective version of Theorem C.
Is there any reference for an effective version (of Theorem C)?
Thanks in advance.

All of the height estimates used to prove Theorem B can in principal be made effective, in terms of the equations defining your family of abelian varieties and the equations defining the section. The point is that the proof uses only functorial properties of height functions, which can be made effective, although with not very good constants, using the effective Nullstellensatz. However, it would be fairly painful to do this in general, especially one would have to also find equations for an appropriate blow-up of the family. As far as I'm aware, no one has done this. For, say, an explicit elliptic surface, it would be much more feasible. The specialization theorem that you quote (Theorem C) is then proven using Theorem B, so Theorem C can also be made effective provided that you know a basis for the group of sections. In other words, you need to compute the Mordell-Weil group of the family, and for now there is no known effective algorithm to do this. So using an effective version of Theorem B leads to an effective version of Theorem C for any explicitly given subgroup of the group of sections.

Thank you for your answer!
